# How to transcribe a score without a rigid tempo?

Tags: theory, notation, rhythm, sight-reading

How do you notate a score that doesn't have a continuous tempo, but ebbs and flows? How can you communicate the rhythmic intentions of the composer to future players? What I was lectured that you need to feel the beat. I feel that there's a change in the beat structure mathematically it's still stays on the tempo but the feeling is different.

Comment: How do you know it "ebbs and flows"?

Comment: I have the recording. But if I write the music and somebody else picks it up how would he know to play as intended?

Comment: Hmmm... I guess you don't. Perhaps clever use of fermatas? On the other hand, how do you know the recording is the "correct" interpretation of the piece? Your question is kind of unclear.

Comment: The recording is a demo from the composer. I'm asking it now in general since I transcribed the piece, how would someone else know how to play it exactly as the composer intended?

Comment: Tempo fluctuation has nothing whatsoever to do with being "a capella". That simply means "without accompaniment".

Comment: @Kilian Foth your right. The question is in general, music that doesn't have a constant tempo. I wrote the question because this is what I was busy with.

Comment: @Nachmen - I took a crack at editing your question to make it more clear. It's still too broad IMO; if you give a specific example (something like "It seems to slow down at the end of each phrase", or an example of what you've notated) it will make it easier to narrow down the possibilities. Feel free to roll back the edit if I didn't catch what you were going for.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't talking about syncopation? Especially in pop and rock, syncopated singing lines, when written out, can look very complicated for a beginner. It would be an interesting question to know how to transcribe such a heavily syncopated singing line.

Comment: To be clear: The question as it stands now isn't clear enough. But if you would include syncopation in the question I would vote to reopen.

Comment: Provide the recording for reference.  Even when notation can be relatively unambiguous, don't be afraid to do this.  We have the facility, use it!

Comment: If I could just send you that audio. Maybe I cant express myself with the right words.

Comment: I made a youtube account. I'm trying now to convert the mp3 to a codex that runs on youtube it's for me something  new. It will take some time untill I get everything straight and in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information, I would guess that at least four things could be going on:

- [Rubato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_rubato): An intentional fluctuation of tempo, with an expressive goal, used in music since Romanticism. This would feel most as 'ebbs and flows' to me. Because rubato is supposed to be only a temporary deviation of the original tempo.
- [Changing meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter_(music)#Changing_meter): The number of beats in a measure can temporarily change. For example, a piece or a song can go from a 3/4 meter to a 2/4 meter for just one measure and then return to 3/4. It can also be more structural: every 4/4 measure is followed by a 3/4 measure, for example.
- [Syncopation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncopation): There are many kinds of syncopation, see the Wikipedia article for that, but often it feels like a missed beat or a note that is suspended over the bar line. Most popular, jazz and rock music is syncopated which can make it difficult to transcribe rhytmically for an untrained ear, especially if there isn't a clear beat played underneath it.
- [Triplets or tuplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet): three or more notes are played or sung in the space of one beat. Sometimes this can give a feeling of a temporary temposwitch.

It's difficult to know what you are dealing with but I would read up on those three and see if one of them qualifies.

Comment: With luck I got it right the youtube link is https://youtu.be/rkkouhdO1a8

Comment: The audio clip is a new production with accompaniment, it's  also much clearer then the audio I had from 1948. It is around measures 15 that were my question was.

Comment: Possible cause #5: ritardando/tempo primo or accelerando/tempo primo.

Comment: @guido This how I wrote it down. I have also by measure 24 the six eights that  repeat four times in the next part. between the beats the sentence with the six eights, the feel changes I left it in 3/4 because mathematically it fits. Put in a rubato sign then piú mosso, then back rubato and back piú mosso. For me it could be 6/8 only for a measure than back this the hard part for me.